# Folder permission

Tags: magento2, nginx, php8

I installed magento2 with LEMP (nginx + php8.1-fpm)

magento root:  /var/www/html/

I am trying to add a seperate folder and execute a phpfile inside this folder in magento root:

/var/www/html/mynewfolder

but when i try to open https://example.com/myfolder/connect.php

i am having :  404 error: Page not found.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your folder inside `pub` folder to access the link as you expected: `/var/www/html/pub/mynewfolder`

If it does not work, edit nginx.conf or nginx.conf.sample depend on which file you are using for config nginx to add the following rule:

```
# PHP entry point for custom scripts
location /mynewfolder/ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

And restart nginx

Comment: If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as **accepted** (the check symbol at the top-left corner of my answer). That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: it doesnt work. Also the folder have to be in magento root;
-/var/www/html/mynewfolder
-https://example.com/mynewfolder/connect.php

Comment: When you create your folder with the path I mentioned you can go example.com/mynewfolder/connect.php

Comment: it doesnt  work...

Comment: @Gkna I've updated the solution in my answer, please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
location /mycustomfile.php {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```